# How to get ROS GSCam to Work in a Docker Container?

Tags: c++, docker, containers, gstreamer, ros

I am trying to use the ROS [GSCam](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam) package in a Docker container to read from a camera stream and publish to a ROS topic. Using GStreamer via `gst-launch` works fine in the container. For example, running

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=10.0.0.20 port=7001 ! decodebin ! filesink location= xyz.flv
```

in the container successfully saves the camera stream to the `xyz.flv` file. When I try to use GSCam using the following commands

```
roscd gscam
mkdir bin
cd bin
export GSCAM_CONFIG="tcpclientsrc host=10.0.0.20 port=7001 ! decodebin ! ffmpegcolorspace"
rosrun gscam gscam
```

the camera stream is published to a ROS topics if these commands are run outside the container, but when run inside the container they result in the following output:

```
[ INFO] [1625351876.482947987]: Using GStreamer config from env: "tcpclientsrc host=10.0.0.20 port=7001 ! decodebin ! ffmpegcolorspace"
[ INFO] [1625351876.486672898]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1625351876.486702714]: camera calibration URL: file:///root/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1625351876.486735225]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/root/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1625351876.486750795]: Camera calibration file /root/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1625351876.486759250]: Loaded camera calibration from 
[ INFO] [1625351876.502708790]: Time offset: 1625351189.738
[FATAL] [1625351876.519311654]: Failed to PAUSE stream, check your GStreamer configuration.
[FATAL] [1625351876.519330710]: Failed to initialize GSCam stream!
```

What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT.** The problem seems to come from this piece of the code:

```
gst_element_set_state(pipeline_, GST_STATE_PAUSED);

if (gst_element_get_state(pipeline_, NULL, NULL, -1) == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
  ROS_FATAL("Failed to PAUSE stream, check your gstreamer configuration.");
  return false;
}
```

Using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547500/how-to-resume-playing-after-paused-using-gstreamer), I can see that the return value of `gst_element_set_state()` is `SUCCESS`, as is the return value of `gst_element_get_state()` for each element of the pipeline (tcpclientsrc0, decodebin0, and appsink0). Strangely however, the output of `gst_element_get_state(pipeline_, NULL, NULL, -1)` is `FAILURE`, which doesn't seem to make sense. What am I missing? Can a pipeline state change fail despite all its elements changing state successfully? or does the pipeline have some other (perhaps hidden) element that fails to change state?

Comment: Have you tried running it without the `ffmpegcolorspace`? It seems like the only difference from your first example.

Comment: Yes, and it gives the same error. Since including `ffmpegcolorspace` in `GSCAM_CONFIG`  works outside the container, I doubt that it is the culprit.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help. You would most likely get better support asking this directly on [ROS Discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/)

Comment: You should try to ask your question on [ROS answers](https://answers.ros.org/questions/) which is identical to StackOverflow but dedicated to ROS specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041641/gscam-cant-find-plugin-but-gstreamer-works-fine) I realized that my problem stemmed from the fact that the common ROS GSCam package (downloaded via ppa) uses GStreamer0.10, but because I was building the package from source inside the Docker image it used GStreamer1.0. Changing the build dependencies to

```
<build_depend>libgstreamer0.10-dev</build_depend>
<build_depend>libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev</build_depend>
```

in the `package.xml` file solved the problem.